Do native-speakers not really vibrate their throats to pronounce those [ ʃ ] sounds in the words with ease?
Like "election" and "situation", their phonetic symbols are /ɪˈlekʃn/ and /ˌsɪtʃuˈeɪʃn/. Their common part is that when we pronounce them, at first we vibrate our throat, then stop when we pronounce ʃ, and vibrate again when pronouncing n.
I almost always still vibrate my throat when I pronounce ʃ. If I try to force myself to stop vibrating correctly, the pronunciation is awful and rusty.

Are you talking about what linguists call voicing, which one can understand as the difference between speaking a word (voiced) and whispering it (unvoiced)?

So far as I know, /ʃ/ is always unvoiced for native Anglophones. Myself, I don't think I'm capable of "voicing" it in the initial position. I'm assuming the distinction here is between assure (unvoiced) and azure (voiced).

What's your native language? Having tried the pronunciations I sometimes end up with a devoiced or slightly lately-voiced /n/, but a voiced /ʃ/ seems wrong. (Polish has /ʒ/ - technically /ʐ/, but sometimes palatalized - as a very distinct sound from /ʃ/, so I might be biased on this).

Hear it here: https://forvo.com/search/election/en_usa/ Also, BrE but the end bits are the same. tion is like shun.

The air from the throat is closed off at [k] in "election". There's no residual voicing that would change the [ʃ]  to voiced.  And in "situation" the dipthong [eɪ] doesn't glide into [ʃ] but terminates before [ʃ] . The [ʃ]  is unvoiced.

@TimR I'm guessing the /-eɪʃn/ example is the relevant one here, with the /ʃ/ between the voiced vowel and the voiced consonant. It's not particularly noteworthy to me, but perhaps it's not a common pattern in OP's native language - just like in Polish you need a linguistics degree to pronounce /θ/.

@TimR Okay, terminate after the [eɪ] makes the pronunciation more easy.

@MaciejStachowski Madarin.

@otakutyrant  "tion" is a morpheme, a Latinate suffix that forms an abstract noun.

@MaciejStachowski  I was thinking perhaps OP didn't quite hear or feel the difference between the final consonant in 'egg' and 'speck'.

I don't know Mandarin, but it should be roughly similar to 为什么 I think - slightly different "sh" (/ʂ/ vs /ʃ/) and in English the /ʃən/ schwa is heavily reduced, but I think it's a similar idea.

Yes the /ʃ/ is unvoiced. You do voice /ɪˈle/ but the /k/ and /ʃ/ are unvoiced.  The final "/n/" is voiced.
It is hard for me to voice the /ʃ/ to /ʒ/ without also voicing the /k/ to /g/.
I clearly pronunces "...ation" differently from "asian", the latter has a voiced consonant in my dialect.  Also Confucian confusion, but more pairs of words like this are rare and the words do sound "similar".
